# Почему записи в InterBase вставляются не по порядку из Delphi?

Tags: база-данных, delphi, interbase

Делаю курсовую работу в Delphi, СУБД InterBase.
В чем суть проблемы в общем, я добавил 10 записей через написанную мной программу, но 11 запись при компиляции программы встаёт между 7 и 8, а не после 10, хотя первые 10 записей добавлялись друг за другом. 
В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если при выборке не указан порядок записи в секции `ORDER BY`, то сервер может возвращать записи в произвольном порядке.

Если Вам нужно отображать записи в определенном порядке используйте секцию `ORDER BY`

Если Вам нужно отображать записи в порядке добавления, то добавьте в таблицу автоинкрементное поле или поле `TIMESTAMP` и сортируйте по этому полю